# Can I use getDisplaymedia in production?

Tags: javascript, w3c

Can I use [`getDisplayMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) in production? I'm a little bit confused because it says W3C editor's draft. What does that mean?

https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/

Comment: You can quickly check support [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Yes, I saw that but still, they mention it as working draft like w3c https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#Specifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [`MediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) is a [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/2004/02/Process-20040205/tr.html).

The W3C uses a four-track recommendation process. A technical report, in this context an API proposal, can be one of the following:

- Working Draft (WD);
- Candidate Recommendation (CR);
- Proposed Recommendation (PR);
- or W3C Recommendation (REC).

WD is the earliest of those, and is generally [the first step of ideation](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/working-draft-draft-document) for proposing a new spec. As a proposal is polished, it can proceed to the next tracks on the list, for example for feedback & implementation from external partners in CR and so forth.

If at any stage, critical flaws are discovered with the proposal, it is reverted to a Working Draft and will need to go through the steps again.

Shortly, this means the `getDisplayMedia()` proposal can be cancelled or completely changed by further revisions. It is [currently supported by some desktop browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#Specifications), but that may either break, change or improve over time.

Keep in mind though that a spec is just that, a spec. Even if a proposal reaches the final recommendation step, it isn't a guarantee that browser vendors will go through the work of implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for clear answers. So basically building a feature under this API is a big risk can I get the timeline for this API like within how many months it will be standardized

Comment: @Nane There is no fixed timeline as far as I know — a draft will need to be discussed by the working group at least once every three months to stay active, but there's no telling how many revisions a proposal can go through or even whether it will end up standardized at all.

Comment: After little research, I think google hangout is using this API and i've tested it in Mozilla it is working does that a good sign for standardization for this API